# mod_rewrite without R=301 doesn't work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the following mod_rewrite rule to currently redirect. But what I really wanted to achieve was for both url's to be working:

Requested URL example: http://sandbox.local/services/userdetails/get.json?username=beebee&ugc_token=abcdef

Rewritten URL: http://sandbox.local/services/userdetails/username/beebee.json?ugc_token=abcdef

Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (username|uid)=([^&]+)&(.*)
RewriteRule ^services/userdetails/get.json$ /services/userdetails/%1/%2.json?%3 [NE,L,R=301]
```

The above rule works, but it redirects the user. If I remove `R=301` then the rule stops functioning, I just get a 404 page. Is there a way to keep the same requested URL, and not do a 301 redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgotten to mention that I was using Drupal.

And because I was using Drupal, I needed to change my `RewriteRule` so that it actually sends the request to `index.php` and that solved the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (username|uid)=([^&]+)&(.*)
RewriteRule ^services/userdetails/get.json$ index.php?q=services/userdetails/%1/%2.json&%3 [NE,L]
```